# How check if Facebook Access Token valid using Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, facebook, validation

I'm developing an iOS app which includes Facebook Login, I have done the login button, but going through the Facebook Test I saw a test to ensure token validity, and if not valid, ask the user to sign in again, I would like to know how to check if a Access Token is valid or expired using Swift 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure do you need something like that, but few months ago I was obligated to implement some of social login to my final project. There is a code I've used, I hope You will be able to use it on some way (there is checking is auth token valid) and if I get what You need it will help You. Greetings. :)

```
    loginButton.isEnabled = false
    if let accessToken = AccessToken.current {
        tryToLoginWithFB(fbToken: accessToken.authenticationToken)
    }   


    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
            if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.tryToLoginWithFB(fbToken: AccessToken.current!.authenticationToken)
                }
            }
        }
        else {

        }
    }
```

Oh, I've almost forgoten - I had to import FacebookLogin, FacebookCore and FBSDKLoginKit and tryToLoginWithFB is my own method which use my (or my friend) app module, now I'm not sure who wrote that part of server-side app but its not important in that situation. :) Ofc that piece of code is from client-side iOS app.

Comment: This just logs the user in, but assume the user removes the app from their app settings permissions, or changes their password, when they reopen your app it should reject the access token and ask for them to sign in again.

Comment: If remember correctly when you where deleting an app or changing password the login stopped working. About permission in settings - it not use Facebook app - you are moved to web page where you have to login. Well I missed that you have to use an login via FB app. So sory for bad answer. :(

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed. I used a graph request in viewDidLoad, if the token is invalid it would ask the user to re-authenticate.